# IPTC metadata to TIFF from EXCEL readable in Bridge

Tags: excel, metadata, tiff, iptc, adobe-bridge

I have an Excel sheet with fields such as [name][url in folder][keywords] ... I am trying to find the best way to write IPTC metadata keywords to my 60'000 TIFF images in order to be able to search through them (with Adobe Bridge) from this Excel file. I have tried exiftool.exe but "Adobe Bridge" cannot read the rendering keywords. I have seen that it may be possible in PHP, but I would like to know if code or software already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Any IPTC library can do it for you. I use Python so for example http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/ would be my tool. Look at the tutorial on http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/tutorial.html

Comment: The links are unavailable